# Color correction using opencv and color cards

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I was looking for automated ways of doing some basic color corrections and I came across this blog post.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/02/15/automatic-color-correction-with-opencv-and-python/

[image]

```
python color_correction.py --reference ref.jpg  --input input.jpg
```

To summarize the blog post, it enables to identify the Pantone color card in a given input image, modify the histogram to match the colors on a reference Pantone color card which has the actual colors. Any color shift due to lighting would be adjusted in the inputted color card.

I had one query as an extension to the use case you described in the blog post. While the histogram matching happens well between the two images cropped to the boundaries of the color cards - it is only now applied to the cropped input image where the color card is present. I want to apply this histogram transformation on the entire input image - beyond the color card as well - how do I go about doing that?
[image]
Can we save the transformation from the match_histpgram function and apply it to the whole image?

Edit 1:
Here is what I tried.
https://github.com/Sum-Al/color_correction

Comment: yes. nothing I can see would prevent you from doing that, except that this person wrote a blog post where I can't see any source code. OpenCV has a whole module for this and I'm sure there are actual examples, either in OpenCV or on other blogs. -- please show your attempt to implement this.

Comment: I included the code I tried.

Comment: so the core is `skimage.exposure.match_histograms` ...

Comment: Yes, that is the core. But if I match_histogram of the whole input image to the reference image, the output might not be desired.

Comment: The colors of the Pantone color card in the input.jpg have been transformed to match that of reference.jpg - Now I want this transformation to be applied to the whole of input.jpg

Comment: see if skimage can give some *description of the result* from the image comparison, which you can then apply to other images. -- you might have to construct that manually, from cumulative_distribution and other calls

Comment: also... `match_histograms` is **definitely the wrong method** to do this. it will destroy image content and the colors will *not* be adjusted to match properly. it merely reshapes histograms. that only *appears to work*, but that is accidental.

Comment: Can you suggest if there is any other straight forward method thne ? I'll try the manual comparison in the meantime.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d7e/tutorial_mcc_basic_chart_detection.html and https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d19/group__mcc.html and a lot of "color science"

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the [skimage tutorial](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_histogram_matching.html), you can derive the following approach, which utilizes any kind of image and not a colour palette:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import data
from skimage import exposure
from skimage.exposure import match_histograms

reference = np.array(data.coffee(), dtype=np.uint8)
image = np.array(data.chelsea(), dtype=np.uint8)
matched = match_histograms(image, reference, channel_axis=-1)

test = match_histograms(matched, image, channel_axis=-1)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 3), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for aa in (ax1, ax2, ax3):
    aa.set_axis_off()

ax1.imshow(image)
ax1.set_title('Source')
ax2.imshow(matched)
ax2.set_title('Reference')
ax3.imshow(test)
ax3.set_title('Matched')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which yields the following result:
[image: Histogram matching]

You can also have a look at the corresponding histograms:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 8))


for i, img in enumerate((image, matched, test)):
    for c, c_color in enumerate(('red', 'green', 'blue')):
        img_hist, bins = exposure.histogram(img[..., c], source_range='dtype')
        axes[c, i].plot(bins, img_hist / img_hist.max())
        img_cdf, bins = exposure.cumulative_distribution(img[..., c])
        axes[c, i].plot(bins, img_cdf)
        axes[c, 0].set_ylabel(c_color)

axes[0, 0].set_title('Source')
axes[0, 1].set_title('Reference')
axes[0, 2].set_title('Matched')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

As you can observe, the histograms of the reference and the 'matched' image look similar after the matching process.

[image: Histograms]

Edit: Note that the `multichannel` argument is deprecated in favor of the `channel_axis` argument as of version 0.19. [Reference](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.match_histograms)

Edit 2: If you want to store this 'transformation' you have two options:

The first and straightforward method is to keep passing your reference image when applying the matching.

The alternative would be to store the relevant quantile for each channel calculated by `skimage`'s `_match_cumulative_cdf` function, which is used by `match_histograms` under the hood and apply the interpolation in the same manner as the function.

```
def _match_cumulative_cdf(source, template):
    """
    Return modified source array so that the cumulative density function of
    its values matches the cumulative density function of the template.
    """
    src_values, src_unique_indices, src_counts = np.unique(source.ravel(),
                                                           return_inverse=True,
                                                           return_counts=True)
    tmpl_values, tmpl_counts = np.unique(template.ravel(), return_counts=True)

    # calculate normalized quantiles for each array
    src_quantiles = np.cumsum(src_counts) / source.size
    tmpl_quantiles = np.cumsum(tmpl_counts) / template.size

    interp_a_values = np.interp(src_quantiles, tmpl_quantiles, tmpl_values)
    return interp_a_values[src_unique_indices].reshape(source.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you.
But your "_match_cumulative_cdf" function will be enough for everything? if  the function only has 2 parameters? In the end, the input image also needs to be processed. _match_cumulative_cdf(source,match,reference)

Comment: If you have a look at how `match_histograms` [works under the hood](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.19.2/skimage/exposure/histogram_matching.py#L24-L85) you will find this very function being used. What it boils down to is the loop from line 73 to 76. This function is called for each of the three RGB channels, so you have to store the relevant quantile for each of the 3 channels. Or as mentioned before, keep passing your reference image to `match_histograms`, which is slightly more compututationally expensive. To circumvent that, store `tmpl_quantiles` and `tmpl_values`

Comment: Can you give me an example code, based on the given Github Script? Iam not a python expert to implement your snippets  the Github Script works nearly perfect, but without the input Image modification

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here is the final working Script. Thanks also for "code-lukas" hints.
You just need an already optimized color input image  and another image which is not color optimized. Both images with Color Card, using [ArUCo Marker](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html)
(you can glue them on the Corners of every imageCard to for detecting)

**https://github.com/dazzafact/image_color_correction**

**input color optimized:**

[image: Input Reference, color optimized]

**Input not color optimize**

[image: Input not color optimize]

**Color optimized Output Image**

[image: Final color optimized Output Image]

user the Script with this arguments

> python color_correction.py --reference ref.jpg  --input input.jpg --output out.jpg

https://github.com/dazzafact/image_color_correction

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import sys
from os.path import exists
import os.path as pathfile
from PIL import Image


def find_color_card(image):
    # load the ArUCo dictionary, grab the ArUCo parameters, and
    # detect the markers in the input image
    arucoDict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL)
    arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    (corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image,
                                                       arucoDict, parameters=arucoParams)

    # try to extract the coordinates of the color correction card
    try:
        # otherwise, we've found the four ArUco markers, so we can
        # continue by flattening the ArUco IDs list
        ids = ids.flatten()

        # extract the top-left marker
        i = np.squeeze(np.where(ids == 923))
        topLeft = np.squeeze(corners[i])[0]

        # extract the top-right marker
        i = np.squeeze(np.where(ids == 1001))
        topRight = np.squeeze(corners[i])[1]

        # extract the bottom-right marker
        i = np.squeeze(np.where(ids == 241))
        bottomRight = np.squeeze(corners[i])[2]

        # extract the bottom-left marker
        i = np.squeeze(np.where(ids == 1007))
        bottomLeft = np.squeeze(corners[i])[3]

    # we could not find color correction card, so gracefully return
    except:
        return None

    # build our list of reference points and apply a perspective
    # transform to obtain a top-down, bird’s-eye view of the color
    # matching card
    cardCoords = np.array([topLeft, topRight,
                           bottomRight, bottomLeft])
    card = four_point_transform(image, cardCoords)
    # return the color matching card to the calling function
    return card


def _match_cumulative_cdf_mod(source, template, full):
    """
    Return modified full image array so that the cumulative density function of
    source array matches the cumulative density function of the template.
    """
    src_values, src_unique_indices, src_counts = np.unique(source.ravel(),
                                                           return_inverse=True,
                                                           return_counts=True)
    tmpl_values, tmpl_counts = np.unique(template.ravel(), return_counts=True)

    # calculate normalized quantiles for each array
    src_quantiles = np.cumsum(src_counts) / source.size
    tmpl_quantiles = np.cumsum(tmpl_counts) / template.size

    interp_a_values = np.interp(src_quantiles, tmpl_quantiles, tmpl_values)

    # Here we compute values which the channel RGB value of full image will be modified to.
    interpb = []
    for i in range(0, 256):
        interpb.append(-1)

    # first compute which values in src image transform to and mark those values.

    for i in range(0, len(interp_a_values)):
        frm = src_values[i]
        to = interp_a_values[i]
        interpb[frm] = to

    # some of the pixel values might not be there in interp_a_values, interpolate those values using their
    # previous and next neighbours
    prev_value = -1
    prev_index = -1
    for i in range(0, 256):
        if interpb[i] == -1:
            next_index = -1
            next_value = -1
            for j in range(i + 1, 256):
                if interpb[j] >= 0:
                    next_value = interpb[j]
                    next_index = j
            if prev_index < 0:
                interpb[i] = (i + 1) * next_value / (next_index + 1)
            elif next_index < 0:
                interpb[i] = prev_value + ((255 - prev_value) * (i - prev_index) / (255 - prev_index))
            else:
                interpb[i] = prev_value + (i - prev_index) * (next_value - prev_value) / (next_index - prev_index)
        else:
            prev_value = interpb[i]
            prev_index = i

    # finally transform pixel values in full image using interpb interpolation values.
    wid = full.shape[1]
    hei = full.shape[0]
    ret2 = np.zeros((hei, wid))
    for i in range(0, hei):
        for j in range(0, wid):
            ret2[i][j] = interpb[full[i][j]]
    return ret2


def match_histograms_mod(inputCard, referenceCard, fullImage):
    """
        Return modified full image, by using histogram equalizatin on input and
         reference cards and applying that transformation on fullImage.
    """
    if inputCard.ndim != referenceCard.ndim:
        raise ValueError('Image and reference must have the same number '
                         'of channels.')
    matched = np.empty(fullImage.shape, dtype=fullImage.dtype)
    for channel in range(inputCard.shape[-1]):
        matched_channel = _match_cumulative_cdf_mod(inputCard[..., channel], referenceCard[..., channel],
                                                    fullImage[..., channel])
        matched[..., channel] = matched_channel
    return matched


# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-r", "--reference", required=True,
                help="path to the input reference image")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--view", required=False, default=False, action='store_true',
                help="Image Preview?")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=False, default=False,
                help="Image Output Path")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
                help="path to the input image to apply color correction to")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the reference image and input images from disk
print("[INFO] loading images...")
# raw = cv2.imread(args["reference"])
# img1 = cv2.imread(args["input"])
file_exists = pathfile.isfile(args["reference"])
print(file_exists)

if not file_exists:
    print('[WARNING] Referenz File not exisits '+str(args["reference"]))
    sys.exit()


raw = cv2.imread(args["reference"])
img1 = cv2.imread(args["input"])
# resize the reference and input images

#raw = imutils.resize(raw, width=301)
#img1 = imutils.resize(img1, width=301)
raw = imutils.resize(raw, width=600)
img1 = imutils.resize(img1, width=600)
# display the reference and input images to our screen
if args['view']:
    cv2.imshow("Reference", raw)
    cv2.imshow("Input", img1)

# find the color matching card in each image
print("[INFO] finding color matching cards...")
rawCard = find_color_card(raw)
imageCard = find_color_card(img1)
# if the color matching card is not found in either the reference
# image or the input image, gracefully exit
if rawCard is None or imageCard is None:
    print("[INFO] could not find color matching card in both images")
    sys.exit(0)

# show the color matching card in the reference image and input image,
# respectively
if args['view']:
    cv2.imshow("Reference Color Card", rawCard)
    cv2.imshow("Input Color Card", imageCard)
# apply histogram matching from the color matching card in the
# reference image to the color matching card in the input image
print("[INFO] matching images...")

# imageCard2 = exposure.match_histograms(img1, ref,
# inputCard = exposure.match_histograms(inputCard, referenceCard, multichannel=True)
result2 = match_histograms_mod(imageCard, rawCard, img1)
 
# show our input color matching card after histogram matching
cv2.imshow("Input Color Card After Matching", inputCard)


if args['view']:
    cv2.imshow("result2", result2)

if args['output']:
    file_ok = exists(args['output'].lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')))

    if file_ok:
        cv2.imwrite(args['output'], result2)
        print("[SUCCESSUL] Your Image was written to: "+args['output']+"")
    else:
        print("[WARNING] Sorry, But this is no valid Image Name "+args['output']+"\nPlease Change Parameter!")

if args['view']:
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if not args['view']:
    if not args['output']:
        print('[EMPTY] You Need at least one Paramter "--view" or "--output".')
```

Comment: You beat me to it, I was just drawing it up. Happy to see the results!